# MissingPluginException No implementation found for method copyText on channel iOS

Tags: ios, swift, flutter

I'm trying to copy text natively with platform channel using flutter. But when ever I call the method to copy text, I keep getting Method copyText not found on channel iOS but works fine on android. Any help would be appreciated. Below is my code

My Flutter Code:

```
const channel_iOS =  MethodChannel('iOS');
const channel_android =  MethodChannel('android');

const String method_copy_text = 'copyText';

  Future copyToClipBoard(String text)
  async {
    if(Platform.isIOS)
    return await channel_iOS.invokeMethod(method_copy_text,{'text': text});
    else if(Platform.isAndroid)
      return await channel_android.invokeMethod(method_copy_text,{'text': text});
  }
```

Xcode to handle method call:

```
import UIKit
import Flutter
import Firebase

@UIApplicationMain
@objc class AppDelegate: FlutterAppDelegate {
    var flutterViewController: FlutterViewController?
    var flutterResult: FlutterResult?
    var methodCallArgs: Any?


    override func application(
    _ application: UIApplication,
    didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplication.LaunchOptionsKey: Any]?
  ) -> Bool {
    self.flutterViewController = FlutterViewController()


    let flutterChannel = FlutterMethodChannel.init(name: "iOS", binaryMessenger: flutterViewController as! FlutterBinaryMessenger);

        flutterChannel.setMethodCallHandler{(flutterMethodCall, result) in
            self.flutterResult = result
            self.methodCallArgs = flutterMethodCall.arguments

            switch flutterMethodCall.method {
            case "openPlayer":
                break;
            case "copyText":
                print("COPIED>>>>>")
                self.copyText()
                break
            default:
                break;
            }
        }

        GeneratedPluginRegistrant.register(with: self)

    return super.application(application, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions: launchOptions)
  }

    func copyText() {
        if(self.methodCallArgs != nil)
        {
            if let copyData = self.methodCallArgs as? [String: String] {
                let text = copyData["text"]
                let pasteBoard = UIPasteboard.general
                pasteBoard.string = text
                self.flutterResult!(["isSuccess": true])
            }
            else{
                self.flutterResult!(["isSuccess": false,"message":"text is empty"])
            }

        }
    }

}
```

Comment: Have you got the solution for this issue, I am also getting same issue. Please help.

Comment: sure, I'll post the solution in a minute

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
import UIKit
import Flutter

@UIApplicationMain
@objc class AppDelegate: FlutterAppDelegate {
var flutterResult: FlutterResult?
var methodCallArgs: Any?

override func application(
_ application: UIApplication,
didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplication.LaunchOptionsKey: Any]?
) -> Bool {
GeneratedPluginRegistrant.register(with: self)

let flutterController : FlutterViewController = window?.rootViewController as! FlutterViewController

let flutterChannel = FlutterMethodChannel(name: "iOS",
binaryMessenger: flutterController.binaryMessenger)

flutterChannel.setMethodCallHandler{(flutterMethodCall, result) in
          self.flutterResult = result
          self.methodCallArgs = flutterMethodCall.arguments

          switch flutterMethodCall.method {
          case "openPlayer":
              break;
          case "copyText":
              print("COPIED>>>>>")
              self.copyText()
              break
          default:
              break;
          }
      }

  return super.application(application, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions: launchOptions)
 }

func copyText() {
     if(self.methodCallArgs != nil)
     {
         if let copyData = self.methodCallArgs as? [String: String] {
             let text = copyData["text"]
             let pasteBoard = UIPasteboard.general
             pasteBoard.string = text
             self.flutterResult!(["isSuccess": true])
         }
         else{
             self.flutterResult!(["isSuccess": false,"message":"text is empty"])
         }

     }
 }
}
```

Comment: Thanks this worked. But one another issue is In "openPlayer" method i want to navigate native UI. Can you help me.